# Selecting specific info from a cell including other info SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to select specific info from a variable I will explain the scenario below.

A module provides data to a logging procedure in my db and inserts that into a table, example:

```
IF(@EventID = 20)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO _LogPvps 
    VALUES (@CharID, @Desc)
END
```

Within the `@Desc` is a string of text with 3x variants that I need to extract and add into another table, string example: (variant 1,2,3)

```
[My: **variant1**, Neutral, no freebattle team] [His(**variant2**): **variant3**, Neutral, no freebattle team]
```

I can split via 1 variant like this, but if possible i need to be able to distinguish all 3.

```
IF @Desc LIKE '%My: Hunter, Neutral, no freebattle team%%His%%, Neutral, no freebattle team%%'
 BEGIN
     DECLARE @CNAME VARCHAR (64)
     DECLARE @JOB VARCHAR (16)

     SET @CNAME = (SELECT CHARNAME16 FROM DB_TEST.._Char WHERE CHARID = @CHARID) 
     SET @JOB = 'Hunter'

     INSERT INTO JOBKILLS 
     VALUES (@CHARID, @CNAME, @JOB, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, @Desc)
 END

 IF @Desc LIKE '%My: Robber, Neutral, no freebattle team%%His%%, Neutral, no freebattle team%%'
 BEGIN
     DECLARE @CNAME VARCHAR (64)
     DECLARE @JOB VARCHAR (16)

     SET @CNAME = (SELECT CHARNAME16 FROM DB_TEST.._Char WHERE CHARID = @CHARID) 
     SET @JOB = 'Thief'

     INSERT INTO JOBKILLS 
     VALUES (@CHARID, @CNAME, @JOB, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, @Desc)
 END

 IF @Desc LIKE '%My: Trader, Neutral, no freebattle team%%His%%, Neutral, no freebattle team%%'
 BEGIN
     DECLARE @CNAME VARCHAR (64)
     DECLARE @JOB VARCHAR (16)

     SET @CNAME = (SELECT CHARNAME16 FROM DB_TEST.._Char WHERE CHARID = @CHARID) 
     SET @JOB = 'Trader'

     INSERT INTO JOBKILLS 
     VALUES (@CHARID, @CNAME, @JOB, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, @Desc)
 END
```

So how can I select each of the variants so I can't set them as a scalar variable and insert them into individual columns in a separate table?

Example:

```
INSERT INTO JOBKILLS 
VALUES (@CHARID, @CNAME, @JOB,
        @variant1, @variant2, @variant3,
        CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, @Desc)
```

Another way of explaining, A - B - C changes depending on what the user ingame does, I need to pick all 3 of them up from the @Desc string and put them into separate columns in another table.

```
[My: **A**, Neutral, no freebattle team] [His(**B**): **C**, Neutral, no freebattle team]
```

Comment: Sorry, could not understand the `variant` parts. Can you describe it in a more simple way please?

Comment: A - B - C changes depending on what the user ingame does, i need to pick all 3 of them up from the @Desc string and put them into separate columns in another table.

    [My: **A**, Neutral, no freebattle team] [His(**B**): **C**, Neutral, no freebattle team]

Comment: Hi there, it seems to me like a problem of splitting this string into sections and then adding them to a table. This problem has been solved a few times on SO. However if the problem is different to that then add some further details as to why your problem is unique. Here is the code to split a string and return a table.

Answer (score 0):

it seems to me like a problem of splitting this string into sections and then adding them to a table. This problem has been solved a few times on SO. However if the problem is different to that then add some further details as to why your problem is unique. Here is the code to split a string and return a table. Needless to say, you may need to modify this to suit your specific needs.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[splitstring] ( @stringToSplit VARCHAR(MAX), @delim VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS
    @returnList TABLE ([Name] [nvarchar] (500))

AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(255)
    DECLARE @pos INT
    declare @len int = len(@delim)
    declare @nextchar int = 1
    declare @startofstring int = 1
    WHILE CHARINDEX(@delim, @stringToSplit) > 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT @pos  = CHARINDEX(@delim, @stringToSplit)  
        SELECT @name = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, @startofstring, @pos-@nextchar)

        INSERT INTO @returnList 
        SELECT @name

        SELECT @stringToSplit = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, @pos+@nextchar+@len, LEN(@stringToSplit)-@pos)
    END
    INSERT INTO @returnList
    SELECT @stringToSplit

    RETURN
END

GO
```